# How to insert value of dynamic form fields in database iusing code in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a problem in trying to store database values in their respective rows inside the database using dynamic form fields. I have provided here the screenshots of my codes and outputs.

[This is my script in adding dynamic form fields in which the form is located in a separate file named load_work_experience_form.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVtqw.png)

[This is the html code for the form I have appended in the my script to add a dynamic form fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPZDq.png)

[This is the look of my dynamic form fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnBJC.png)

[This happens to be the wrong output inside the database in which data values do not store in their proper record. I am attempting to insert 2 records of work experience but it seems that it has created 4 records.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSogr.png)

```
The source code for adding into the database is supplied below. Kindly help me in fixing this problem. Thanks. More power:

<!--ADD WORK EXPERIENCE TO DATABASE -->
  <?php
    require'../admin/php/db_connection.php';
    if(isset($_POST['update_profile']))
    {

      if (isset($_POST['employer'])) {
        foreach ( $_POST['employer'] as $value ) {
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_work_exp (employer) VALUES ('$values')");

        }}

        if (isset($_POST['job_position'])) {
        foreach ( $_POST['job_position'] as $value ) {
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_work_exp (job_position) VALUES ('$values')");

        }}
//some more codes here for Work From and To. This website does not accept alot of codes. But the codes here are just like the ones at the top.

    }
  ?>
<!--ADD WORK EXPERIENCE TO DATABASE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you have every time the same fields with dynamic rows:

```
<!--ADD WORK EXPERIENCE TO DATABASE -->
  <?php
    require'../admin/php/db_connection.php';
    if(isset($_POST['update_profile']))
    {
        if (isset($_POST['employer'])) {
            for ($i = 0, $nCount = count($_POST['employer']); $i < $nCount; $i++) {
                $employer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['employer'][$i]);
                $job_position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['job_position'][$i]);
                $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO tbl_work_exp (´employer´, ´job_position´) VALUES (´' . $employer . '´, ´' . $job_position . '´)');
            }
        }
    }
  ?>
<!--ADD WORK EXPERIENCE TO DATABASE -->
```

You must add there the other fields also...

The problem of your logic is that you do for every field a insert but you need only one insert for one row.

And please don't use mysql library in php, it is better to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you pass each value separately. I strongly suggest to change your HTML markup to group each value, but that's not the goal here. As for your current problem, this is a quick solution that can help you through. Picking up from your current code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['update_profile'])) {
    $profileFields = array('employer', 'job_position');
    $profiles = array();

    foreach ($profileFields as $field)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
            foreach ($_POST[$field] as $key => $value) {
                if (!isset($profiles[$key])) {
                    $profiles[$key] = array();
                }
                $profiles[$key][$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
        $tableCols = implode(",", array_keys($profile));
        $profileValues = implode("','", array_values($profile));
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_work_exp ({$tableCols}) VALUES ('{$profileValues}')";
    }
}
?>
```

Give or take a few tweaks or special treatment for each field. This is very generic code just to give you a guide.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Button_name'])){
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['employer_name']); $i++){
$query="INSERT INTO table_name(employer_name,employer_age) VALUES ('".$_POST['employer_name']."','".$_POST['employer_age']."')";
$result=mysql_query($query);}}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$count_post_value = $_POST['first_name'] //this is value of text box //


for($i=0; $i<$count_post_value; $i++) 
{ 
if(trim($_POST["first_name"][$i] && $_POST["last_name"] && $_POST["remarks"]!= '')) 
{   

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table_name(first_name,last_name) VALUES('".$_POST["first_name"][$i]."','".$_POST["last_name"][$i]."')"); 
if($sql) 
{
echo "<script>alert('Inserted Successfully');</script>";
}


else 
{
echo "<script>alert('ERROR');</script>";
}

}

}  

?>
```